# WSO2 Docker image : The creation time is ahead of the current time

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

So we are using WSO2 Docker image and Customizing it but when we are using

```
wso2/wso2mi:4.0.1-SNAPSHOT-centos
```

OR

```
wso2/wso2mi:latest
```

OR

```
wso2/wso2mi:4.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

My API giving below response

```
{
    "httpCode": 502,
    "userMessage": "Invalid response from remote host",
    "developerMessage": "The creation time is ahead of the current time.",
    "details": {
        "detail": "wsse:InvalidSecurityToken"
    },
    "errorCode": "S:Sender",
    "timeStamp": 1624341823703,
    "transactionId": "CIP-urn:uuid:0f709b7d-a64e-4f2b-99bd-9c7db2117903"
}
```

But when i downgraded it to `1.2.0`  then rest-api working fine without above error.

And with `1.2.0` i am getting another issue and its throwing

> [2021-06-21 16:15:42,528]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:Orders}
> Keycloak_validate_session_out_Seq:message = Execution started, payload
> = {"keys":[{"kid":"sIdlyiT5kp_UHeCDBv1XStHP2vlmxf7LrwmF7-kEWtw","kty":"RSA","alg":"RS256","use":"sig","n":"nxYUCkCq-pZ9CMjE9eyk8ciwJTgNO79p0jrGCClVPzLYbURvTabEC5B3YdHu1etie_2Ob1tBvhgMsRn96Q8c7cPis9HGsMgLO2ze-BpdW1qdQ1yhGD_XcefDALIbvjmiV_2qR7qnIORqV5TvhOeRXiXxQGUNnG_qxrUF_hO2hfKqrFdhVoKQtOQZsihTljM8tUfS6HZH092hoFcleKQtN29p9N9qsljDj99eMpsH1xAZSdz3oa663zbw03taA35W9sOnGmZRNwFoVe781tFNflj--2Kpd7fE6P-DO-mNWrbqVia1271IjZZczpTWGStcKhNuvD_ZyF5bx1sqtEd0iw","e":"AQAB","x5c":["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"],"x5t":"_eS_AqDYrcISKGjwdvwpFMafgFs","x5t#S256":"b8p0TX62hFJ74LCm4uL4hJA5eErSggz_qsTyDV81Yj4"}]}
> [2021-06-21 16:15:42,576] ERROR {MicroIntegratorRegistry} - Couldn't
> create resource: keycloakkey-kid [2021-06-21 16:15:42,577] ERROR
> {MicroIntegratorRegistry} - Error when adding a new resource
> org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Couldn't create resource:
> keycloakkey-kid
> at org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry.handleException(MicroIntegratorRegistry.java:655)
> at org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry.createFile(MicroIntegratorRegistry.java:830)
> at org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry.addResource(MicroIntegratorRegistry.java:813)
> at org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry.newResource(MicroIntegratorRegistry.java:562)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__190._c_script_0(:3)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__190.call()
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__190.call()
> at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__190.exec()
> at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:55)
> at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediateForInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:395)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:290)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediate(ScriptMediator.java:258)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
> at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:37)
> at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.SwitchCase.mediate(SwitchCase.java:69)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.SwitchMediator.mediate(SwitchMediator.java:134)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:214)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:239)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:244)
> at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:267)
> at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:809)
> at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:309)
> at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:583)
> at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:197)
> at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
> at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:285)
> at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

So agian i have to Downgrade to version [1.1.0](https://hub.docker.com/layers/wso2/wso2mi/1.1.0/images/sha256-aa8a68b67a22475c1afff37329d91c553ecb49998aec51be94921386e7ae21df?context=explore)

and with this version everything looks fine. Can WSO2 team look and tell me whats wrong with the version we used.

Comment: The response you are providing is coming from your endpoint, not from the Micro Integrator. Could you please add your mediation steps? It will also help us with the log stack trace, as it is from a script mediator (I believe because Rhino trace)

Comment: Thanks for your reply..But Version change fixing the issue .Which Meditation you are looking exactly  ? May be i am not able to understand it clearly.

Comment: I was meaning the resource/sequence/endpoint ... Which is the request? ... there is no much context. That response is from the backend itself, maybe you could debug it to see the MI is changing something between versions (HTTP headers or something similar), but under what circumstances does the backend response contains"The creation time is ahead of the current time."?

Comment: @usuario Again my doubt end with one point how its working with version 1.1.0?